# Preserving data in the APPDATAFOLDER directory when uninstalling the application with a Wix installer

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3

I'm storing some some files in the application data (`APPDATAFOLDER`) folder when I'm installing my Wix application. Wix creates the sub-folder in the `APPDATAFOLDER` correctly but when uninstalling, it also removes the folder.

I'd like to preserve all the data in the `APPDATAFOLDER` by not removing it when the user uninstalls the application. Is there a simple way I could do this?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, windows installer won't remove anything that it didn't install (unless you explicitly tell it to do that with [RemoveFile](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_removefile.htm)). So if you are concerned about preserving user data that was created after the installation, you may not have to do anything.

If you are talking about installed components, you could mark them with `Permanent="Yes"`. That will prevent them from ever being uninstalled.

Answer (score -2):

Besides doing nothing, u can use the standard WiX flag `NOT REMOVE` on ur components, files and directories. it is very easy. e.g.

```
 <Component Id="" Guid="" >NOT REMOVE</Component>
```

and WiX will flag this component to only install and patch, but not to uninstall.

Comment: Your answer is not accurate. First of all, the syntax is incorrect - the Component element can't have the inner text. In case you mean Condition element instead, then I don't think it makes much sense to specify NOT REMOVE as a component condition. And moreover, it doesn't give the behavior the author of the question is asking about...